# Tinycards and Anki

Tags: online-learning, anki, duolingo

Duolingo has a flashcard program called [Tinycards](https://tinycards.duolingo.com/). Anki is a well-known flashcard program.

What are the major differences between these two, when it comes to learning languages? Both of them at least claim to be based on spaced repetition, and both allow making custom decks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are three articles that talk about the two apps ([1](https://www.mickmel.com/tinycards-vs-anki/), [2](https://felixwong.com/2017/08/tinycards-vs-quizlet-vs-anki-the-best-app-for-language-flashcards/), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/tinycards/comments/50fg42/can_i_replace_anki_with_tinycards/)).

They are both spaced repetition systems, but here are some key differences:

- They have a different look and feel, so that is a subjective factor. Tinycards is more modern, while Anki is arguably starting to look dated.
- Tinycards decks are limited to only 150 cards. This is a problem if you like big decks. Anki decks have no practical size limit.
- Tinycards can connect directly to your Duolingo account and has shared decks (that the original owner still controls), but Anki has a lot of shared decks that instantly become "yours" (free to make changes) once you download them.
- Anki has more overall functionality, so if you like to add pictures and audio, etc, then you have more control.